# Hive table with nested JSON as string value

Tags: json, amazon-s3, hive, presto, hive-metastore

I am trying to create a table from nested json.
The second layer of the the JSON is very complex and I don't want to keep the schema of that JSON in the table definition with struct column.

I am looking for solution that allow me to keep it as string.

for example:

```
{
"request_id": "3dbd4ee3-96fc-4342-bd62",
"payload": { < COMPLEX NESTED JSON >  },
"timestamp": 1569161622
}
```

I was trying to use the following create statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE data (
request_id string,
payload string,
`timestamp` int
)
ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION 's3a://bucket'
```

Is there any `SerDe` property/mapping I can use to define the nested object as String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe`  `SerDe`

for more info on this SerDe refer [link] (https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde)

Hope this helps

Comment: I saw that, what type of column should I use ? string ?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you want .. and I believe you should be able to query later with get_json_object